# Why is Nuget creating the "Packages" folder in the project's parent folder?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Why is Nuget (version 4.2.0) always creating the "Packages" folder in the (VS 2017) project's parent folder? I created a plain test project right now (no solution, no .sln file), it happens even then.

Does that mean there is a nuget.config somewhere telling Nuget to do so and that I have to create a nuget.config for every project in order to get the "Packages" folder created in my project folder, as expected?

I tried on my second PC, it's the same behavior there.

I found a NuGet.Config in c:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\NuGet which gives me no hint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

There is no NuGet.Config in %ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\

Comment: NuGet will create a packages folder in the same directory as the solution if you are using a packages.config file. The NuGet.Config file can be used to choose a different location. There is no concept of a packages folder for a specific project - the default location is always based on where the solution file is.

Comment: Even if there isn't one???

Comment: If you are using a packages.config file then NuGet will create a packages directory for the packages that will be referenced by your project. If you do not want to have a packages directory with your solution you should look at using a project.json file or the PackageRefence items in your project.

Comment: It's OK for me, just caused me trouble since it used to create to Packages folder within the project folder in former versions and I had to fix all references. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Nuget creating the “Packages” folder in the project's parent folder?

The packages path is relative to the solution folder **by default**, we could not instruct nuget to create a packages folder for each project. Let me explain the reason for this default setting.

According to the [NuGet.Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file), we could use `repositoryPath` to change the default installation path:

```
<config>
  <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\package" />
</config>
```

It can be a relative path and this file is based on the current solution. However, **each project in one single solution cannot have a different packages path by using one relative path setting or absolute path setting.** So the default packages path is relative to the solution folder rather than project.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the behavior of nuget's packages folder. Just a follow up question, when does this package folder gets created in the solution folder? I have an older solution that has this folder. But when I create a new branch in TFS, I need to manually copy the packages folder to the new branch. Why? Doesn't nuget write that folder when the packages are restored?